# retrieving value through fetch (sending values from javascript to php file)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, reactjs, fetch

I'm very new to fetch and don't know Ajax.

I'm trying to send data from JavaScript file (node.js server) to PHP file(Apache server).

I'm sending 2 JSON values through JavaScript fetch as "a" and "b".

**my code looks like this.**

```
fetch('http://localhost/react_task/react-webpack-boilerplate/php/api.php', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    a: 2,
    b: 1
  })
}) .then(function(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response.text()
  }
  throw new Error(response.statusText)
})
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
})
```

Can somebody tell me how to retrieve value of a and b in my PHP file? 
I'm working with react.js

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`. if that's blank, then you probably have to read the json from `php://input`

Comment: can you please write in answer.. what exactly you mean???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because you’re passing a JSON blob via a `POST` request, you’ll need to decode the JSON before attempting to read the data in it. You should also use PHP’s [Filter Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php) to safely retrieve user input.

Here’s some sample code (untested):

```
<?php
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($input);
$filtered_a = filter_var($input->a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$filtered_b = filter_var($input->b, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

echo "Safely received numeric inputs: a: {$filtered_a} b: {$filtered_b}";
?>
```

More details on the how and why of using the filter functions can be found in the [introduction page](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.filter.php) of the documentation.

Comment: this does work out man .. it says " SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0 "

Comment: your solution seems to be fine, but not working for me.

Comment: @ManpreetOberoi: My bad, looks like you’re sending the `POST` body as JSON. In that case, you can’t directly use the filter input functions. I’ll update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can get posted values by `$_POST` parameter in PHP.

For testing, paste these lines into your api.php

```
if($_POST["a"]=="2" && $_POST["b"]=="1")
{
    echo "I posted 2 and 1";
}
```

Now `response.text()` should return `I posted 2 and 1`.

Comment: Undefined index: a in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\react_task\react-webpack-boilerplate\php\api.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br        it is giving me this error.. any solution for this.

Comment: Using superglobals like `$_POST` directly is very bad practice. Use PHP’s [Filter Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php).

Comment: Also this wouldn’t work because OP is sending JSON via POST.

Comment: @AbrahamVegh: uh, what? don't spout garbage. superglobals are there for a reason.  it's what you DO with them what MIGHT be bad. There's nothing dangerous WHATSOEVER about the above code.

Comment: @MarcB: I didn’t say it was dangerous, I said it was bad practice, because like you say, it *can* be dangerous.

Comment: still, don't spout garbage. you're saying the equivalent of "Don't use a car. driving is bad practice. use a chauffeur"